# update angular typeahead data using angular-ui bootstrap

Tags: angularjs

The fix is to step away and think about it, rookie mistake.. i had my trace in the wrong spot and the data was getting loaded AFTER i changed the items...

so call off the dogs, but thanks for listening...

How do i change angular typeahead data?  Nothing seems to update the initial list of data.

js:

```
$scope.items = [{name: 'jack', age: 44}, {name: dave, age: 55 }];
$scope.selected = '';

$scope.change = function() {
   $scope.items = [{name: dave, age: 55 }]; // typeahead data never sets to this
   $scope.items = []; // typeahead data never sets to this
});
```

html:

```
<div data-ng-click="change()"></div>

<input data-typeahead="person as person.name for person in items | filter:$viewValue" data-ng-model="selected" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple rookie mistake.  The data was being reloaded (due to route change) after i was changing the values.